# Whatsapp: In which manner android's whatsapp msgstore.db.crypt is differ from blackberry's whatsapp msgstore.db.crypt

Tags: android, encryption, blackberry, blackberry-10, whatsapp

Using XDA forum's method we can easily can decrypt android and Blackberry's whatsapp db.crypt file but we can't decrypt whatsapp db.crypt of any Blackberry device.

I want to know in which manner it get decrypt in the blackberry?

Comment: Get a job with WhatsApp and ask them.